# How many need tables in mongoDB for use fosuserbundle symfony 3.2?

Tags: mongodb, symfony-3.2

- I have created User collection and field(id,username,email,password) but fosuserbundle is not working
- So please give me how many document collection need for fosuserbundle use in symfony 3.2

Comment: i have made custom login and register is working fine  but when i  am using fosuserbundle not working so how many tables create for use fosuserbundle  in symfony 3.2

Comment: please specify question correctly

Comment: i want to know only how many tables need for use fosuserbundle

Answer (score 1):

We need for fosusertables the tables which required by fos user are,

·         fos_user

·         fos_group

·         fos_use_group